# How to set priority on button in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have button1 and button2.

How can I set priority to those buttons. I want if I click them both at the same time only 1 button should perform, the other button should wait the other button to be done.

It's like `fifo` algorithm, but I want to use `PRIORITY SCHEDULING` algorithm. I need help Threading on button using setpriority() method min and max. how to implement that on android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean like **isButton1Done** with a default value of *false*.
In the on click listener of buttons1 you can set it to *true*, and in the on click listener of button2 you have just to check if **isButton1Done** is *true* or *false* .. if it's *true* you can proceed with the onclick method.. if it's *false* just return

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to check if you priority button is pressed or not:

```
Button1 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!b2IsPressed) {
            // handle it
        }
    }
});
boolean b2IsPressed = false;

Button2 b2.sbutton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            b2IsPressed = true;
            // Do whatever you want
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            b2IsPressed = false;
        }
})};
```